# Claim copyright over modified code with MIT license in a javascript file

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

I'm making a web app that I would like to own the copyright of. I used some javascript code from CodePen under MIT license (I believe) that I heavily modified in one of my javascript files.

Is it ok to mention the original source and author but still claim copyright on the file as in the following header?

```
/**
 * Pure javascript pixel editor library
 *
 * @summary Pixel editor library
 * @author Antoine Drutly
 *
 * Includes code from Justin Herrick on codepen https://codepen.io/jah2488/pen/Gimzn under MIT license
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Antoine Drutly
 *
 * Created at : 2019-08-17
 */
```

Should I mention the use of the MIT code elsewhere, for example in a license.txt file?

Does claiming the copyright on the javascript file prevents people from using the modifications from the original code?

**EDIT**

Reading the common form of the MIT license again and with the help of the answer of gnasher729, I answered most of my questions. The new code added in the file is copyrighted by me and the part that hasn't been modified is still copyrighted by the original author. I don't need to mention somewhere else the use of the MIT code.

However, the copyright notice below and the permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software. This indicates that I should copy the MIT license and the name of the author above every portion of the code that I haven't modified. This is pretty much infeasible, so my guess is that mentioning the original author with a link to the original code is enough. I should also add the MIT license copyright notice in the file as well but this will add a overhead to every client downloading the website, so I probably won't.

```
Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are parts that have been created by someone else, those parts are copyrighted by their creator, and the new parts are copyrighted by you.

You need to check the license of the original code to see what you have to do to have permission to use and modify the original code.

Comment: But where do you cite the authors? Can I e.g. put it in the header of the index.html file, can I make a dedicated page that I link in the footer, must it be visible on all pages that use the code, etc.

Comment: @gnasher729 what does "parts" mean? if there is a line of code unmodified from original then should each such line have MIT license for it?